# Android imageview id not resolved,

Tags: java, android

```xml
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivPopup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logout"
    android:layout_marginStart="144dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`enter code here`
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvProfileName"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
/>
```

Here is the java code to refer the ImageView

```java
final ImageView ivPopup = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPopup);
```

For some reason, the android cannot resolve the ivPopup in R.id.ivPopup

Main Activity

```java
    public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG ="Menu";
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ImageView ivPopup;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
        TextView tvProfile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvProfile);
        tvProfile.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button btnNotes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNotes);
        btnNotes.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button btnTimeTable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTimeTable);
        btnTimeTable.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button btnClass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClass);
        btnClass.setOnClickListener(this);
        TextView tvProfileName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvProfileName);
//        Bundle extras =getIntent().getExtras();
//        String user1 = extras.getString("username");

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        ivPopup = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPopup);
        ivPopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(HomePage.this,ivPopup);
                popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, popupMenu.getMenu());

                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        Toast.makeText(HomePage.this,"" + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    }
        });
        popupMenu.show();
    }
```

Comment: Pl share your activity or fragment code where you are referring to the respective layout file and the view by id.

Comment: try invalidating caches and restart

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean code
2. Rebuild code
3. Try to `Invalidate Caches & Restart.`

if It's still not working then change your id from `ivPopup` to something else in XML as well as JAVA